# Application- vs database- generated keys

Tags: java, jdbc, primary-key

I'm taking Spring Batch as example to illustrate my question since I thought about it when looking at the Spring Batch docs.

If you look at [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/metaDataSchema.html#metaDataIdentity) section, you can read:

> However, they are not database generated keys, but rather they are generated by separate sequences. This is necessary because after inserting one of the domain objects into the database, the key it is given needs to be set on the actual object so that they can be uniquely identified in Java. Newer database drivers (Jdbc 3.0 and up) support this feature with database generated keys, but rather than requiring it, sequences were used.

Until now, I always proceeded as follows:

1. Create the entity (no identifier is assigned yet - e.g. key is null)
2. Use a repository to persist the entity. The database generates a unique identifier for the entity. The identifier can be accessed using the JDBC API.
3. Set the identifier to the created entity

What are the pros and cons of using this method versus the application-generated keys method?

Thanks,
Mickael

Comment: What are the requirements? I would say its nearly always better to let the database do it, because when you have a relational database you can retrieve data using `JOIN` whereas this is not possible without  keys, primary/foreign, in the database.

Comment: I don't see how it is related to JOIN. If I use a sequence and get a unique ID before persisting the entity, at the end, the row in the database will have an assigned unique primary key which can be used for foreign keys. Therefore, I will still be able to use JOIN.

Comment: Better to have the database do it because it can allocate and use the key atomically. You can't.

Comment: @EJP If the next available key is fetched using a sequence (like Spring Batch does), the application has a way to allocate a unique key atomically (provided that the same sequence is always used).

Comment: @EJP Sorry, I didn't read your comment correctly. The allocation + assignment will not be done atomically. However, when the key is allocated, it can't be used by another application and therefore there should not be any issue during assignment.